# Creation of a Grid/Matrix using views in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, nodes, entities

Does anyone know of a good way to automate the creation of matrix/grids/tables like this?

[image]

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to create a grid that can show links to other nodes  based on an entity (or node) reference.

There could be many of these grids on the site so I'm trying to figure out an automated way to create them (i.e. go to a page like /grid/1/3 and the 1/3 tells the page what columns and rows to pull in - and then based on references how to fill the grid)

It's a little confusing to get across what I mean but hopefully it's understandable.

Comment: Have you seen that there is a grid view in Views already?

Answer (score 1):

*There is a module for that* - if you are using Drupal 7 check this:
[Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid)